# Do I need to add a platform when submitting a Facebook Messenger chatbot for approval?

Tags: facebook-messenger, facebook-chatbot

I want to submit my chatbot on FB Messenger for approval. Do I need to select a platform in the Settings tab e.g. a Website?

The chatbot will just be used on a FB page, not on any other platform.

I can submit currently on the Messenger tab, but not the App Review page, which asks for a platform to be added. So, also unsure should I submit on the Messenger page or on the App Review page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can answer this myself now: - if the chatbot is only to be used on a Facebook page, you do not need to select a platform before you submit for approval. If you're using it elsewhere (app, website etc.) you do.